# Declaring a Date object within the prop tag in application context

Tags: java, spring, date, dependency-injection, properties

I am trying to do the following:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="path.to.some.class">
  <property name="config">
    <prop key="startDate"> a java.sql Date object </prop>
  </property>
</bean>
```

How can I instantiate a Date object within the prop tag?

Thanks

Comment: java.sql.Date or java.util.Date?

Comment: java.sql - but I could live with either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to have an instance of java.sql.Date - afaik that is for JDBC mapping. If you are using java.util.Date (which I suspect you are).

Then the example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/PropertiesSettingDate.htm) works for me.